# Drag the center of an item

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml, qtquick2, drag

I have an `Item` that is a little large. I want to **resize** it when dragging and ensure that the **center** is always dragged. The following is a trial (In order for simplicity, I don't set the center of the `Item` to the mouse position here, neither do I change the size.), however the position `x` will be reset immediately after I change it. Is there any way to avoid this.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello Quick")

    Rectangle{
        id: item_
        width: 300
        height: 300
        color: "red"

        MouseArea{
            id: drag_
            anchors.fill: parent

            drag.target: item_
        }

        states: State{
            when: drag_.drag.active
            PropertyChanges {
                target: item_

                x: 100
                y: 100
            }
        }

        onXChanged: console.log("item_.x: ", x)
    }
}
```

The output:

```
qml: item_.x:  100
qml: item_.x:  0
qml: item_.x:  1
qml: item_.x:  2
qml: item_.x:  3
qml: item_.x:  4
qml: item_.x:  5
qml: item_.x:  6
qml: item_.x:  7
qml: item_.x:  8
qml: item_.x:  10
```

Comment: Hi there! What is your question specifically? You mention resizing and dragging the centre but then say it's simplified. Is the problem just with the `item_.x` being displaced?

Comment: I think the State is giving you some troubles, when I remove it, the rectangle stays after dragging. Can you live without?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Resing and dragging the center is the goal. In order to drag the center, I think I need to change x first. If there exists other solutions, then changing x is not necessary.

Comment: @Amfasis perhaps not. I need to reset all properties if drop is not accepted or cancelled .

Comment: @TrebuchetMS what's more, if I don't need to change the size then I don't need to change the center as the mouse may be left outside after resizing.

Comment: @cqdjyy01234 How does your drop work? Are you using a DropArea then performing checks onDropped?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS almost except I plan to use the keys property.